# Shell script to run a command and send the commands output as a report in email

Tags: bash, shell, email, report

I am trying to write a shell script which will run a command to ssh into multiple machines and store the output in a variable and send it as a report via email.Here is what I have in the script as of now:

```
#!/bin/bash 

DcEmitterConn='yinst ssh -H test.out "netstat -a | grep ES | grep 25019 | wc"'

SUBJECT="DC-Connections"
EMAIL="abc@abc.com"
EMAILMESSAGE="report.out"
echo $DcEmitterConn> $EMAILMESSAGE
#send email using /bin/mail 
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"< $EMAILMESSAGE
```

After executing the above command in the script it would ask me for a password and then would print the requested output. The problem i am facing in the above script is that I am not able to store the command output in the variable and print it in the email body. Can someone please let me know if I am missing something.

the output would look something like this:

```
abc@dh1.data.ac2.abc.com's password:  (yinst-pw) 
     40     240    3560
abc@dh2.data.ac2.abc.com's password:  (supplied by yinst-pw)
     50     300    4450
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried it..it does not work for me.

Comment: To output in var you should use this syntax `var=$(code)`, in your case
`DcEmitterConn=$(yinst ssh -H test.out "netstat -a | grep ES | grep 25019 | wc")`

Answer (score 0):

You should put double quotes around $DcEmitterConn on line 8. And you can avoid the temporary file:

```
SUBJECT="DC-Connections"
EMAIL="abc@abc.com"
yinst ssh -H test.out "netstat -a | grep ES | grep 25019 | wc" | /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"
```

Comment: this sounds logical but I am still getting an email with no content. I guess the problem is at where I have put in a password initially for the above command to print the output. What step should I include to take care of the password part?

Comment: You might want to setup [passwordless SSH connection](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152)

Comment: Is it possible that the output actually is sent to stderr ? Try prepending the command with  2>&1

Comment: #!/bin/bash 

SUBJECT="DC-Connections"
EMAIL="abc@abc.com"
yinst ssh -H test.out "netstat -a | grep ES | grep 25019 | wc" 2>&1 | /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"
this is what i did...but still no luck...i think i would need to set up passwordless SSH connection...